# Программа, подставляющая отсутствующие гласные и пробелы

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть примитивный "шифр" - англоязычный текст с удалёнными гласными и пробелами, например: `"thrsmnstrsnmhdndthrsnthngcnd"`. Само собой, что-то можно идентифицировать "вручную", но далеко не всё.

Существует ли какой-либо способ решения данной проблемы?

Прошу подсказать возможные пути решения проблемы - а дальше я уже как-нибудь разберусь за пару лет, поскольку единственное, что приходит в голову мне - учиться писать и обучать нейросети.

Comment: Правильные мысли приходят. Можешь прочитать про частный случай - [нормализацию Маркова](http://mathhelpplanet.com/static.php?p=normalnyye-algoritmy-markova). Ну и гуглить по запросам автоподстановки. Из близкой тематики можешь почитать эту статью [Нестерука](https://nesteruk.wordpress.com/2016/12/17/callsharp-project/). С точки зрения алгоритма, ты выбираешь буквы с начала строки, формируя из них слова. Сформировал первое слово - отрезал, работаешь с оставшейся частью строки. Но параллельно пробуешь более длинные первые слова. И так, пока не закончатся. Выбираешь законченные цепочки слов.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ссылки и информацию - принял к сведению, буду читать, буду искать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего эта задача не имеет решения. Все дело в том, что теряется слишком много информации при вырезании гласных. Я написал простенькую программу, которая работает простым перебором:

```
static List<string> cleanWords;
static List<string> filteredWords;

static Dictionary<string, List<string>> cache;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var words = File.ReadAllLines("google-10000-english-usa.txt");
    var r = new Regex("^[a-z]+$");

    cleanWords = words.Select(w => w.ToLower()).Where(w => r.IsMatch(w)).ToList();
    filteredWords = cleanWords.Select(w => w.Replace("e", "").Replace("y", "").Replace("u", "").Replace("i", "").Replace("o", "").Replace("a", "")).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < cleanWords.Count; i++)
        if (filteredWords[i] == "")
        {
            cleanWords.RemoveAt(i);
            filteredWords.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;
        }

    //string input = "thrsmnstrsnmhdndthrsnthngcnd";
    string input = "hll";
    cache = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    var result = Parse(input).OrderBy(s => s).ToArray();
    foreach (var str in result)
        Console.WriteLine(str);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

И собственно сам рекурсивный метод перебора:

```
private static List<string> Parse(string input)
{
    if (input == "")
        return new List<string> { "" };
    if (cache.ContainsKey(input))
        return cache[input];

    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < filteredWords.Count; i++)
    {
        if (input.StartsWith(filteredWords[i]))
        {
            result.AddRange(Parse(input.Substring(filteredWords[i].Length)).Select(rem => cleanWords[i] + " " + rem));
        }
    }

    cache[input] = result;
    return result;
}
```

Подавая на вход очень простую строку `hll` (от слова hello) я получил 7500 результатов. Большинство из них не имеют смысла, но среди них есть и вполне осмысленные:

```
hall
hi all
hill
he ill
hell
hey all
holly
holy lie
hull
```

И это еще мой код не работал со словами, где одни только гласные (например a, you). Можете представить сколько вариантов будет на длинных строках.

Comment: Эх, этого я и боялся. В любом случае, огромное спасибо за потраченные время и усилия. Попытаюсь понять ваш код (не потому, что он плохой, а потому что я нуб) и подумать над нейросетями.